# Multivariate and multistep LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, forecasting

Giving [this example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) (section: Train On Multiple Lag Timesteps Example), in order to predict the next 6 hours of Pollution based on the previous 2 years data, should I just set n_hours=17520, and the number of future steps I want to predict (set n_out=6) ?

Otherwise, I've read somewhere that I should also modify the Dense layer units to the number of the future steps to predict (here is 6), however, it always returns an error. What would be the problem ?

Thank you

The modified code:

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg

# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# specify the number of lag hours
n_hours = 17520
n_features = 8
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, n_hours, 6) # predict the next 6 hours
print(reframed.shape)

# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24 *2
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
# split into input and outputs
n_obs = n_hours * n_features
train_X, train_y = train[:, :n_obs], train[:, -n_features]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :n_obs], test[:, -n_features]
print(train_X.shape, len(train_X), train_y.shape)
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_hours*n_features))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

Edit:
I have changed the value of Dense layer units to 6 and the `train_y.shape[1]` as well as `test_y.shape[1]` to 6 as follows:

```
# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# specify the number of lag hours
n_hours =48
n_out=6
n_features = 8
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, n_hours, n_out)
print(reframed.shape)

# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24 * 2
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]

# split into input and outputs
n_obs = n_hours * n_features
train_X, train_y = train[:, :n_obs], train[:, :6]#I put 6 instead of -n_features
print(train_X.shape, len(train_X), train_y.shape)
test_X, test_y = test[:, :n_obs], test[:,:6] # I put 6 instead of -n_features
print(test_X.shape, len(test_X), test_y.shape)

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
train_y = train_y
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_hours, n_features))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
train_y.shape

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False) 
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], n_hours*n_features))

# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

The error I've got :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-8e17d1d76420> in <module>
      9 # invert scaling for forecast
     10 inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
---> 11 inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
     12 inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
     13 # invert scaling for actual

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    404                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    405 
--> 406         X -= self.min_
    407         X /= self.scale_
    408         return X

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26227,13) (8,) (26227,13)
```

Comment: As you have already read, you have to set the output layer (Dense) to have 6 neurons (one for each prediction hour), it should match with the shape[1] of train_y. If it doesn't work, there must be an error in the data, please add the error message you are getting.

Comment: Okay @Pedrolarben I have changed the code and added the error, please check it with me again. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error output shows, the problem happens when you try to invert the min-max scale operation. The problem is that you have fit the scaler with all the columns and now you only need to reverse the scaling for the first column of your dataset. To solve that, the tutorial's author concatenates the predicted column to the rest of the attributes, but you cannot do that as you are predicting more than one value for each row. A possible solution could be this one:

Change this

```
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, -7:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]
```

with this

```
# invert scaling for forecast
pred_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)).fit(dataset.values[:,0].reshape(-1, 1))
inv_yhat = pred_scaler.inverse_transform(yhat)
# invert scaling for actual
inv_y = pred_scaler.inverse_transform(test_y)
```

Comment: Hello @Pedrolarben, Thank you or your answer it does solve the broadcast problem thanks. I've tried to plot the results and I've got multiple graphs in one  is that normal ? I've used this code :
Ps: I'm new in python

pyplot.title("Actual vs Prediction", fontsize=14)
pyplot.plot(inv_y, label='Actual')
pyplot.plot(inv_yhat, label='Predicted')
pyplot.legend(loc="upper left") 
pyplot.xlabel("Time Periods")
pyplot.ylabel(dataset.columns.values[0].title()) 
pyplot.show()

Comment: it is normal that you are getting multiple graphs. You should use a for loop to iterates over the validation dataset. Something like this: for i in range(10): pyplot.plot(inv_y[i], label='Actual')  pyplot.plot(inv_yhat[i], label='Predicted') pyplot.show(). This will create 10 plots comparing the actual and predicted values of the first 10 examples.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer @Pedrolarben.
But, I guess that using the "#invert scaling for forecast" part of the code keeps the values between 0 and 1 even though the "inverse.transform" function is used. Normally, the values should be over 1 !

Comment: There was a mistake, I was using values thinking it was the dataframe values, but, actually, it was the already preprocess data. Use `dataset.values` instead and it should work

Comment: I figured that out, thank you so much @Pedrolarben :D  I have one last question please: Since I'm making 6 steps prediction I thought that I'll only have 6 future values (based on the last 48 values (n_hours)), plotting the predicted and real values, I've noticed, as you see, that I have a lot of graphs and values. I'm confused can you please explain that to me. I'll be so grateful.

Comment: Well, imaging being in moment t, your model has learnt to predict t+1,t+2,..., t+6. However one second later, your model also has the real value of t+1, so it's able to predict from t+2 to t+7. For this reason, you have already 2 predictions for t+2 ... t+6 one prediction done at moment t and another at moment t+1. As we're doing the moving window preprocessing, at the end we'll have 6 predictions for each validation moment. This happens simply because we're working with time and we can't stop it :). I recommend you this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much for your time :D